# Collectionview in tableview error : Index out range and cell's content changes when i swipe

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

I'm I'm trying to show the collectionview in the tableview, but I keep getting the error index out of range, and the contents of the cells change when I scroll.What is this reason ? I tried many different ways but couldn't solve it

View Controller

```
    var featuresVM = [FeaturesModel]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        configure()
    }
    
    
    func setupUI() {
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)
        tableView.rowHeight = 200
            
        featuresVM =   [
            
            FeaturesModel(imageName: "images", titleModel: [
            Features(title: "Name", overview: "4"),
            Features(title: "Price", overview: "5"),
            Features(title: "Count", overview: "6"),
            Features(title: "Date", overview: "7")]),

            FeaturesModel(imageName: "images", titleModel: [
            Features(title: "Ürün Adı", overview: "19"),
            Features(title: "Ürün Fiyatı", overview: "20"),
            Features(title: "Ürün Fiyatı", overview: "21"),
            Features(title: "Ürün Fiyatı", overview: "22"),
            Features(title: "Ürün Fiyatı", overview: "23"),
            Features(title: "Ürün Fiyatı", overview: "24"),
            Features(title: "S.K.T", overview: "25")]),
            
            //And more
        ]
    }
}
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return featuresVM.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return featuresVM[section].imageName
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.viewModel = featuresVM[indexPath.section].titleModel
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

### CollectionView delegate,datasource

```
extension CustomCell : UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewModel.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else {
         return UICollectionViewCell()
      }
      cell.titleView.text = viewModel[indexPath.row].title
      cell.overView.text = viewModel[indexPath.row].overview
      return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return CGSize(width: baseCollectionView.bounds.width / 2 , height: baseCollectionView.bounds.height)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      return 0
  }
```

}

Comment: Try set indexPath.row -> indexPath.item in func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: No didn't work @neskafesha

Comment: Do I need to set collectionview's datasource and delegate as viewcontroller? @neskafesha

Comment: what you have inside viewModel ?? , and can you explain more what is inside what . numberOfRowsInSection in table view shouldn't be 1

Comment: @DholfaqarMohammedAlharazi 1 row in a section is valid, especially when that section is a collection view.

Comment: If cells are changing content when scrolling, you've probably got either a reuse issue or they are loading some async content.  Without the cell code it's not possible to tell though.  At what point are you getting the index out of range?

Comment: viewmodel = [Features] @DholfaqarMohammedAlharazi

Comment: try numberOfItemsInSection in collectionView = viewModel[section].count , in first section the count is 4 and in the 2nd section is 7

Comment: yes true @DholfaqarMohammedAlharazi

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aHfpdAmK70 
I uploaded the video to youtube. Index error and cell change are seen in the video. @DholfaqarMohammedAlharazi

Comment: @flanker I upload video

Comment: I solve this problem , this problem reason collectionview datasource and delegate tableviewcell . I  defined it in viewcontroller collectionview delegate and datasource and solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem , this problem reason collectionview datasource and delegate tableviewcell . I  defined it in viewcontroller collectionview delegate and datasource and solved.